# Animated snapping Header in react native reanimated and scroll view

Tags: react-native

I am trying to animate a top header via the scroll events from the scrollview.

1. When the user touches the screen and scrolls up, the nav bar follows the inverse of the scroll position with the help of diffclamp. i.e., `translateY = multiply(diffClamp(this.scrollY, 0, NAV_HEIGHT), -1)`
2. After the user releases the touch, I run a timing function to animate the Header, to either hide or show depending it on the snap point. i.e.,

   - If the `diffClamp node > Navigation heigh/2`, then snap point node returns 0.
   - Else snap point node returns (-) Navigation height.

This works fine on single scroll touch and release. But suppose on the first release I released the touch on - 20 (this.scrollY), and the animation ends. Later, if I touch and scroll, the scroll transition happen from the earlier released position, i.e., -20 , instead of 0.

You can check out the [snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@kakarn/animated-navigation-bar).

I suppose it would have been solvable if I could set the diffclamp node to the snap point, but I guess it is not possible. Could you help how to solve this issue?